# Run web server behind router which I can't change anything in

Tags: web-server, firewall, router

I'm currently at a schools network and can't change anything in the routers configuration but I still want to be able to run a web server. I've scanned the router for some open ports and only found out that 8080 is the only open and the router reponds with "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" when I try access it.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: One solution would be speaking with the school's network administrator and discussing your options.

Comment: @jscott, yeah, that is a solution but a later one because it's the middle of the night here and I need a solution quite fast. But thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: How can my question be off topic?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not directly. I.e. you're probably not going to be able to stand up a local web server and convince the router to send incoming requests to it.

However, it might be possible to work around the router by, say, creating an SSH connection to some cloud-based server and have the server forward incoming HTTP traffic to your local machine. I've done exactly that for web server development/debugging when the web server absolutely has to be reachable publicly.

A tool that helps with that (at least for development work) is [`localtunnel`](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/).

More of the gritty details: http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/sshtips.htm

Comment: It worked very good. However, this feels like a temporary solution. Is there any more permanent fix for this problem?

Comment: @Victor, I don't know of any more permanent solution. Other than working with the network admins to get the router to permanently forward certain traffic to your web server.